# UICollectionView with cells wrapping content

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using UICollectionView with cells that contain a few UILabels.  The text in the UILabels can vary in length and may be many lines, so I need to adjust the height of the cells based on the content.  My cell layouts were done in Storyboard.  So far I have not found a way to do this without some tedious and difficult programmatic layouts.  Is there an easier way to do this?
I know you can use a delegate for UICollectionViewFlowLayout and implement this method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
   sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 //how do I get size of my cell?  
  return size;
```

}

In this method you cannot get an instance of the cell, so makes it difficult to return the size.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you'll have to use some font metrics to measure the height of your label at the appropriate width. You'd need to figure out what the text should be for the relevant indexPath, then use the NSString method

[`– boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3aattributes%3a)

to figure out the size your label will be when you eventually lay it out. You can pass something like `CGSizeMake(250, CGFLOAT_MAX)` to the first argument to constrain the width.